# Wpf Properties.Settings doesnot save

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, application-settings

I working on a Wpf UserControl that launches from another app. And I need to save list of my custom objects and load it after application restart. So I tried to store my list in settings file. My code is:

```
List<Bar> lst=new List<Bar>();

//...
//Adding to list;
//...

ProjectName.AppSettings.Default.MyList = lst;
ProjectName.AppSettings.Default.Save();
```

When I call my UserControl in app everything works fine. List is saved. But when I restart an application there is no data in the list.

What can I do? Maybe there is some better ways to store my list?

**UPD:**
I found that if I will use a basic type(int for example) everything works fine to. So the problem is with list.

Comment: do you read the the values in your List on start? `lst = ProjectName.AppSettings.Default.MyList;`

Comment: @WiiMaxx Of course. And Thats works fine while I don't restart a application.

Comment: Does issue appear when you start an app from IDE, exe file or both?

Comment: when you're saying `from another app`, are you trying to save the other app's AppSetting?

Comment: @VMaleev issue appears in both cases.